# How to batch insert rows into SQL Server using VBA

Tags: vba, sql-server-2012, batch-insert

I've got a requirement to insert data into SQL Server 2012.
The data we need could be large in quantity( over 100k possible).
I know how to insert with single rows but that's too slow in this case.
Is there any other way to do this in a batch way?

Thanks for any reply

Comment: What is your source?  Are you familiar with ADO? Have you tried doing a simple "INSERT INTO yourTable SELECT  FROM yourSource"? You should be able to take this approach with an Access table, Excel worksheet, or flat file.

Comment: Also, do you have to do the actual inserts from VBA, or can you execute a SQL string that can BCP or OPEN ROWSET the file?

Comment: I tried to perform a INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM worksheet, but it kept running into error. I thought it was due to the different connections( one for local worksheet, the other one for database).

Comment: Now I'm SELECT all records from the data source worksheet and set the recordset to an array and loop through the array to INSERT INTO database table. I think this might be faster than looping through the worksheet. But it's still to slow.

Comment: What's the error you're encountering?

Comment: Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Ace.OleDb.12.0' has been denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.                  This is the err description I got.

Comment: You may need to enable ad hoc access to the SQL Server. 
 https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61739/help-with-sql-server-error-ad-hoc-access-to-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oled    https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1573624-392-1.aspx    https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68fe9ebd-a2f4-4ac4-853b-d4ca35dc1a3e/ad-hoc-access-to-ole-db-provider-microsoftaceoledb120-has-been-denied?forum=sqldataaccess    If you let me know the source format and post some code, I'll take a look